# How to connect a Windows client to an OSX Server with AFP

Tags: macos, client, afp

We are using OSX servers and clients with AFP (Apple Filing Protocol) and want to connect the only Windows (Vista x64) client to the server shares without having to enable SMB. Is there still any AFP client for Windows available?

All that I've found are Windows AFP servers, but that's not what we need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"AFP". That brings me back.

I'd go with SMB for the simple reason that I'd trust Apple or whoever to correctly implement SMB before I'd trust Microsoft or whoever to properly implement AFP. Not because of relative competence, but because AFP is strange, and does things in unexpected ways.

I've implemented an AFP server, so learned this the hard way.

Comment: Our users make heavy use of AFP/HFS-specific features such as coloring files and folders. Is it safe to mix AFP with SMB? We fear that providing both services at the same time might lead to problems. 
Unfortunately we can't just move to SMB for the other users' sake.

Comment: When you said "client", I thought you meant a transparent client. Obviously, Windows doesn't know anything about coloring folders, so transparent is out. I'd look to see if Apple has a software catalog or something, that might show who sells a program that's effectively a "Finder" on Windows. Also, BTW, this is now clearly "not programming related", and so should be closed.